# AES cryption quellcode

Tags: c++

I need a small, like a two pieced, version of an [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption. I googled and found *[AES - Advanced Encryption Standard](http://www.lomont.org/Software/Misc/AES/AES.cpp)*  (source code), but the code seems to be written for Windows and I need a multi-platform one.

Is there any other small version of an AES encrpytion known or a fix for the used functions which seem to be unknown on Linux?

My compiler says that those are unknown functions:

```
./aes/AES.cpp:198:17: error: ‘_rotl’ was not declared in this scope
./aes/AES.cpp:608:20: error: ‘_rotr’ was not declared in this scope
```

I also got:

```
./aes/AES.cpp:764:34: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
./aes/AES.cpp:770:36: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
```

As those should be known, considering those includes:

```
#include "AES.hpp"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: You need to include `<cstring>` to get `memset` and `memcpy`.

Comment: You just have to replace the rotate intrinsics by either C code or a suitable replacement for your platform.

Comment: **solve the key management problem first**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference implementation for AES can be found here: http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm. The main source file only includes `<stdio.h>`, but it doesn't even depend on that; you should have absolutely no problem using it on any platform.

Answer (score 4):

Use a well-tested crypto library, like [cryptlib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) or [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), instead of some random snippets found on 40th page of search results. Depending on what you're doing, you probably also should be using higher-level constructs rather than AES directly.

Comment: well i just need some encryption, nothing fancy. Nothing really serious. It is just a small project i am doing to stay in shape. So i favor something small even though it might not be as good.

Comment: Even if this is *really* just to "stay in shape" and you'll never unleash this on anyone else, you're still not doing yourself a favour by doing something half-assed like that. If you want a quick and small library, check out `libmcrypt` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

since this comes up high in a google search for that error, here's what I did for my program which was refusing to compile on an x64 CentOS system that lacks ia32intrin.h:

```
#if !defined(_rotr) && (defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))
static inline unsigned int _rotr(unsigned int n, const int count) {
 asm volatile (
  "rorl %1, %0;"
  : "=r" (n)
  : "nI" (count), "0" (n)
 );
 return n;
}
#endif
```

as avakar mentioned, you need to include cstring, or alternatively string.h, to get memset and memcpy.

the code for `_rotl` would be identical except for the opcode mnemonic, which would be `roll`.