# C++ crypt libraries in boost or any else

Tags: c++, cryptography, libraries

I would like to ask if boost has some libraries useful for crypting tasks.

well if boost does not have such libs I would like to hear what crypt libraries would you recommend.(some widly used libs)

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crypto library for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674401/crypto-library-for-c)

Comment: oh I'm realy sorry :/ didn't look well.

Comment: Personally I've found `mcrypt` very friendly. It's a C library, but very clean and easy. A simple wrapper class for C++ is readily written.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take a look at [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), [libtomcrypt](http://libtom.org/), [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). There are many more of them for sure.

Comment: tnx, where can I lean about crypto++ for example, some reference or whatever.

Comment: @codekiddy maybe this would be helpful for you: http://andreyvitdev.blogspot.com/2005/10/crypto-usage-sample.html , http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Sample_Code , http://www.bitvise.com/users-guide.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a finished boost cryptography library.  According to [this page](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction), there was a work in progress, but it hasn't been worked on since 2009 and is not even at beta, so probably best avoided.

Personally, I have had good results with [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I enjoy using [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/)! Simple and rich.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Boost doesn't cover crypting (yet) but I ask something [comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600557/aes-cryption-quellcode) and [CryptLib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) and [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) were mentioned.